# Transform list of elements to table

Tags: python

I have a list of elements which looks like this (for clarity written as table)

```
ID  | OtherID
-------------
1     1
1     2
1     3
2     1
2     3
```

Which I want to transform to a table like this, where `ID 1` and `ID 2` are the values of `ID` from the table above:

```
OtherID | ID 1 | ID 2
---------------------
1         True   True
2         True   False
3         True   True
```

What's the best way to do this? Both `ID` and `OtherID` are coming from the database. If it's done better in the database I'm happy for any advice.

**Update:**
With the help of @7yl4r given in the comments I have implemented a first version using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 3],
        [3, 1],
        [3, 4]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ID', 'OtherId'])

table = df.pivot(index='OtherId', columns='ID', values='ID').fillna(0)
table[table > 0] = 1
table.replace({1: True, 0: False}, inplace=True)

print(table)
```

Is there a simple method without using pandas?

Comment: What are `ID 1` and `ID 2`? Also, please show us your attempt (code)

Comment: The general term for what you are trying to accomplish is a "long to wide" transformation. Searching for that should give you some useful results.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this code and adapt/optimize it for working with your database

```
# input table format [(ID, OtherID), ...]
input_table = [
    {'ID': 1, 'OtherID': 1},
    {'ID': 1, 'OtherID': 2},
    {'ID': 1, 'OtherID': 3},
    {'ID': 2, 'OtherID': 1},
    {'ID': 2, 'OtherID': 3}
]

# get distinct list of ID
id_set = set([rec['ID'] for rec in input_table])

# get distinct list of OtherID
other_id_set = set([rec['OtherID'] for rec in input_table])

# create empty output_table
output_table = list()

# iterate over distinct other_id
for other_id in other_id_set:

    # create row with 'OtherID' column
    row = {'OtherID': other_id}

    # iterate over distinct id
    for id in id_set:

        # record { 'ID': id, 'OtherID': other_id } exists ?
        exists = False
        for rec in input_table:
            if rec['ID'] == id and rec['OtherID'] == other_id:
                exists = True
                break

        # add current ID column
        row['ID ' + str(id)] = exists

    # add row in output_table
    output_table.append(row)

# print result
print(output_table)
```